# Excel 2016 conditional statement in combination with an OR?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

Is it possible to combine a conditional statement w/ BOOLEAN OR, like:

=IF(x=1 **OR** 2) do x o/w do y

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this syntax

`=IF(OR(A1=1,A1=2),TRUE,FALSE)`

or.....

`=IF(OR(A1={1,2}),TRUE,FALSE)`

replace TRUE and FALSE with the required outcomes